# Raspberry Pi Hosted, Network LED Manager

Tags: networking, led, server

I have been looking for a while and I have not found an answer. I am looking for a vendor neutral, LED manager/server that would let me manage all of the wireless LED strips already in my network. Like for example, I would like to change them all into the same color within a web interface. No breadboards, no strips directly connected to the pi itself. Just a remote browser interface, all of the led lights automatically detected by the software over the network. Does something like this even exists?

Thanks in advance and sorry of there's already an obvious answer.

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have good experiences with Domoticz and RFXCom. But it depends quite a bit on your led-strips